# What does it mean if a person says that a particular datastructure can enumerate?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

I read a previous question on this forum on datastructures and I quote

> "Array - represents an old-school memory array - kind of like a alias for a normal type[] array.
>   Can enumerate. Can't grow automatically. I would assume very fast insertion and retrieval speed."

What does it mean when he says that arrays can enumerate?

Comment: you can loop through the items of the the array using a foreach-loop and IEnumerator interface or using a for-loop and the Index-Property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A data structure is enumerable if you can loop through elements in that structure such as in an array, or collection that might contain many objects.

A class does not have to implement IEnumerable to be enumerable with a foreach loop, although I would consider it 'best practice'. It is enough for the class to have a method called GetEnumerator that returns an object with a MoveNext method and Current property e.g.

```
internal class Test 
{
    public Enumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new Enumerator();
    }

    public struct Enumerator
    {
        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            return false;
        }

        public object Current
        {
            get { return null; }
        }
    }
}
```